# Is it possible to have multiple keys to a certain value?

Tags: java, hashmap, key

For example if I want to find a person's details , either by providing its name(key1) , or name+last(key2) name, or his phone number(key3)... 
Can that be implemented in a hashmap?

Comment: No. You must have only one key mapped to one value.

Comment: You can use objects in a hashmap.

Comment: @TheLostMind But you can map many keys to identical values.

Comment: @Tichodroma -  I meant, you can't map *same* key to *different values*. i.e, the key should be unique. I can have `name`, `id` as seperate keys and then map them to the same object (value). But that is also not a good design.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Please reconsider your design.

Comment: Because I'm trying to make a little app (university exercise) that is basically a phone book . Now I need there to be options like adding a new contact, removing m and search for a contact.
I didn't want to restrict my searching options to just the name for example. Instead , I wanted to be able to choose, whether I want to provide the input with the number or the name of the person, and that way to find the contact's details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible (but see below).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SOPlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Person> people = new HashMap<>();

        Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Doe");
        Person jane = new Person("Jane", "Smith");
        people.put(joe.getFirstName(), joe);
        people.put(joe.getLastName(), joe);
        people.put(jane.getFirstName(), jane);
        people.put(jane.getLastName(), jane);

        for (String key : new String[]{"Joe", "Doe", "Jane", "Smith"}) {
            System.out.println(people.get(key));
        }

    }

    private static class Person {

        String firstName;
        String lastName;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + '}';
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Person{firstName=Joe, lastName=Doe}
Person{firstName=Joe, lastName=Doe}
Person{firstName=Jane, lastName=Smith}
Person{firstName=Jane, lastName=Smith}
```

But it is **a very bad idea** to mix the semantic of keys. Stick to one. Use either the first name for or the last name **for all keys**.

Comment: An answer to the question?

Comment: No, it is not. He wants to have multiple keys for a value.

Comment: And that's what I do. Multiple keys point to identical values.

Comment: Though this does solve the problem, I personally think this is a bad design. Any requirement that requires you to do this should be re-considered

Comment: @TheLostMind I agree with you. It is very bad design and I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly using hash-map. But you can write it yourself and it is not hard to implement.